# Setting Attribute Of python Method In Class

Tags: python

I can't set an attribute of a function inside of a class.
Minimal example:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        pass

f = Foo()
f.bar.attribute = True
```

For me, this throws an `AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'attribute'` (`setattr(f.bar, 'attribute', True)` instead of the last line throws the same error).

Is there a more elegant or pythonic way to set the attribute than `f.bar.__dict__['attribute'] = True`?

Comment: You are defeating the whole purpose of class encapsulation if you want to modify a variable that is within the scope of a class method from outside that method. If you really need to control an attribute from outside, it should instead go as method parameter. You could have "attribute" as method parameter with default value (may be True is what you want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method objects don't have anywhere to store their own arbitrary attributes. Also, method objects are created on each access - `f.bar is not f.bar` - so even if you could set an attribute on a method object, it wouldn't be there when you tried to look for it again. This means that you *really shouldn't* try to set attributes on method objects.

When you ask for an attribute a method object doesn't recognize, it forwards the request to the underlying function, so `f.bar.__dict__` is really `Foo.bar.__dict__`. Setting entries in that dict will set attributes on the underlying function, so they'll be visible through every instance of `Foo`, and methods of separate instances won't have independent attributes.

Whatever problem you were trying to solve by setting attributes on method objects, you should find some other way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't set an attribute of a function inside of a class.

Actually, you can. What you tried to do was set an attribute of the particular method off of an *instance* of the class. That, you can't do (AFAIK).

`Foo` is the class. Try `Foo.bar.attribute = True`. This will affect *all* instances of `Foo`, not just `f`. For example:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        pass

f = Foo()
Foo.bar.attribute = True
print(f.bar.attribute) # outputs True
z = Foo()
print(z.bar.attribute) # Also outputs True
```

In fact, `f.bar.__dict__['attribute'] = True` actually sets it at the class level as well:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        pass

f = Foo()
f.bar.__dict__['attribute'] = True
print(f.bar.attribute) # Outputs True                                                                                                                                                                       
z = Foo()
print(z.bar.attribute) # Also Outputs True
```